# Why Are My Form Elements Saving as Individual JSON Elements in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I have a form for a dummy dog walking appointment scheduler, and the task is to save the data to `localStorage` (databases are not allowed). So far I have managed to save the elements fine individually, however I am now working on saving the input data as an array using JSON.

My lecturer has given us a great tutorial, however it only explained hard-coded arrays. I have managed to save the data from the form into its own array, but it is saving each element (name, address, number etc) in its own index. I would however like each users entire form input to be saved to the one index.

```
bookings - [0]{ booking one }
           [1]{ booking two }
           [2]{ booking three }
```

I am also having trouble that old data is not clearing afterwards.. of course in the final product I want the data to remain, however I have old data from earlier today before I made the arrays - I have tried clearing cache and the data is still showing.

Here's what I have:

```js
   $("#submit").click(function () {
 
// prepare
var formData = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
// get all stored as Array []
var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings') || '[]');

for (formData = 0; formData < localStorage.length; formData++) {
// insert and save
    localStorage.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify([formData]));
}
});
```

```html
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" onsubmit="return setAction(this)" class="col-sm-6">
  <h3>Book your dog walk now</h3>
  <!-- BOOKING FORM -->
  <div class="row">
    <p>Tell us about yourself first..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="display_fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
    <input type="text" id="display_lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="number" id="display_number" onchange="validateContact()" placeholder="Contact Number" name="Number"
      required>
    <input type="email" id="display_email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <p>When should we pick your dog up?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="date" id="display_sdate" class="datepicker" name="sdate" onchange="checkStartDate()" required>
    <select name="stime" id="stime" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a time</option>
    </select>
    <select name="duration" id="display_duration" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Duration</option>
      <option value="half an hour">30 mins</option>
      <option value="one hour">1 hour</option>
      <option value="one and a half hours">1.5 hours</option>
      <option value="two hours">2 hours</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <p>Where should we pick up/drop off your dog?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" name="address" required>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" placeholder="Post Code" name="postcode" required>

  </div>

  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" onsubmit="return setAction(this)" class="col-sm-6">
  <h3>Book your dog walk now</h3>
  <!-- BOOKING FORM -->
  <div class="row">
    <p>Tell us about yourself first..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="display_fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
    <input type="text" id="display_lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="number" id="display_number" onchange="validateContact()" placeholder="Contact Number" name="Number"
      required>
    <input type="email" id="display_email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <p>When should we pick your dog up?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="date" id="display_sdate" class="datepicker" name="sdate" onchange="checkStartDate()" required>
    <select name="stime" id="stime" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a time</option>
    </select>
    <select name="duration" id="display_duration" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Duration</option>
      <option value="half an hour">30 mins</option>
      <option value="one hour">1 hour</option>
      <option value="one and a half hours">1.5 hours</option>
      <option value="two hours">2 hours</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <p>Where should we pick up/drop off your dog?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" name="address" required>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" placeholder="Post Code" name="postcode" required>

  </div>

  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS (updated based on a reply)
The code was replacing the previous form data rather than adding it to the next index, I thought a for loop may be the answer?

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
 
    // prepare
    var formData = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
    // get all stored as Array []
    var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings') || '[]');
    
    for (formData = 0; formData < localStorage.length; formData++) {
    // insert and save
        localStorage.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify([formData]));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately localStorage does not have index keys, but you can use this approach. It will allow you to store the array under one key. Having parsed it, you can work with it.

```
  $("#submit").click(function () {
    // prepare
    const formData = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
    // get all stored as Array []
    const allData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings') || '[]');
    // insert and save
    localStorage.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify([...allData, formData]));
  });
```

Comment: On the tutorials my lecturer has went through, there are indexes.. I have tried this code and it is not returning anything as it seems we are getting 'bookings' before setting it? It is returning an empty array on dev tools.

Comment: I check this code before post here. it works  - allData grows

Comment: Ah wait it is working! I put in allData rather than formData, silly me! Thank you so much that was really bugging me :)

Comment: Quick other question.. It is only saving one form submission array.. If I want to save another array into the Bookings, how would that work? I thought this would work but it's not.

Comment: You save each form data in one bookings as array. [{first submitted data},{second submitted data}, ... e t.c. ]

Comment: Yes I have that, but if I wanted to make a second booking in the next index with different data? So I have multiple bookings?

Comment: just create new name  localStorage.setItem("otherBookings", otherBookings);

Comment: Or you can use 2d array  [[{...01}, {...01}], [{...10},{...11}] ]

Comment: Ah, no that wont work as it would all be hard coded? I thought to use a for loop but not sure how to do it with stored data.

Comment: "if I wanted to make a second booking in the next index with different data? So I have multiple bookings?" - but I think my code works as you need

Comment: Your code overwrites, my - doesn't, The loop is not needed here at all - I used spreading ES6

Comment: I am using your code exactly and it is overwriting :(

Comment: I will update my question with my for loop suggestion.. and a picture of results?

Comment: I have simplified the form. After submitting, I clear and fill in the list at the top of a page. Try it https://codesandbox.io/s/booking-tb5pz?file=/index.html Also try refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you, it works great on your example but not in my work unfortunately.. I can't understand why.

Comment: Can you make and share git repository with all your code? Or try compare each of code yourself.

Comment: No but I can make a codepen, I only have 2 pages and a JS/CSS doc, hold on.

Comment: ok just do it) I'll fork it and left with my comments

Comment: I think its been solved, another user has suggested a slight change and now it is working, thank you for your help too!

Comment: I found 2 errors in your code  https://codepen.io/Danwillzoom/pen/PoGQaEv?editors=1111

1) html row 11 and 2) js row 127  after it code works. Always check console! Good Luck

Comment: Still giving me errors, I have taken the code into a separate JS file and still doesn't work. I had code working but now thats also not working, I give up :(

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18OOsNXKPSaK9XVYd6JLoFsqrdrecxlNz/view?usp=sharing